# jQuery - execute function after data is loaded

Tags: jquery, document-ready

I have a page which exports HTML to PDF. There are few user controls in the page which loads the data using AJAX request. Once the data is loaded, i have to send the generated page to third part tool which will export the sent HTML to PDF which is done by calling a JS function and sending page body as a parameter.

Everything works fine except that i have to delay the execution of sending the data to the third party tool by 5 seconds in the document.ready event otherwise it sends blank page. If i set the interval to 5 seconds, it works fine.

I was wondering if there is any event i am missing that can notify me that page has loaded the data.

Comment: why not export the page in the callback of the AJAX function ? can you include the code that loads the page ?

Comment: What code are you using to load the data?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ -> find `success` handler

Comment: the reason i cant call export in AJAX callback is because there are 10 user controls that make AJAX request on load. It is not in my control to not let them do it. Also i have to send page body to the export function. I dont want to write new export code as deadline for the project is close by.

Comment: You're downloading the PDF in the background and when done call a JS function that takes all the data as a parameter? Sounds nasty to me.

Comment: i am not downloading the PDF in the background. I never said i am. I am passing the HTML to a function which takes care of exporting it to PDF.

Comment: Is your problem that you're making multiple AJAX calls, and you need a way to know when all of the applicable AJAX calls have completed?

Comment: no. my problem is to know when the data is finished loading in the respective controls.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout will execute a function when a certain amount of milliseconds has expired

```
$(document.ready(function() {
  function redirect()
  {
    // do redirection
  }

  setTimeout(redirect, 5000);
});
```

Although..

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'something.pdf',
  dataType: 'application/pdf',
  success: function() {
    // though you are safer and better doing it when the ajax event has actually fired
  },
});
```

Comment: thats what i am doing right now. I am looking for an alternative to it. It works but is risky.